# Custom shaped Border in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing, border

I am trying to create a TabControl which matches the style of an existing tab control I use in WinForms, and one of the features of that is that it has tab button shapes like those found in VS (slant on the left, other edges square).

I am just starting out in WPF, so maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, but I figured I needed to get a Border, and attach it to a Path, so that I could specify some geometry for the border... However, I just can't find any useful information. I found a 'FreeFormContentControl' class on S/O, but that is for masking content to a specific shape, rather than drawing a border around it in a specific shape.

If somebody could point me in the right direction I'd be very much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify Border's properties BorderThickness and CornerRadius in terms of individual value for each side, for example:

```
<Border CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0"/>
```

It will have topLeft and topRight corners radius set to 2 and left, top and right border parts set to 2.

**UPDATE:**

Also you can create your custom Adorner. More info provided [by this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(VS.85).aspx)

And simply add some self sized geometry to TabItem control template. More info on it provided [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032(VS.85).aspx)

**SAMPLE**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                                <Path x:Name="path" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Fill="{StaticResource LightBrush}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Data="M 0,20 L 0,5 5,0 100,0 100,20 "/>
                            </Viewbox>

                            <Border Visibility="Visible"
            x:Name="Border"                                                                  
            Margin="5,1,0,1" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ContentSource="Header"
              Margin="12,2,12,2"
              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />

                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: But that will give me a rectangle with rounded corners. The tab shape in VS is a slant on the left, not a straight edge...

Comment: Still not really what I'm looking for - an Adorner wouldn't change the basic layout of the Border, and there is nothing in the second article that gives any hint as to how you might attach Geometry to a TabItem template?

Comment: See added sample and pay attention on ViewBox and Path inside it. Used colors you may define by yourself.